# Bing AppID is invalid

Tags: python, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to use the Bing Translator API for Python, and for some reason it is telling me that I have an invalid AppID. I get the error:

> ArgumentException: Invalid appId
>    Parameter name: appId: ID=[string of 4 numbers].V2_Json.Translate.[string of 8 numbers/letters]

I have checked that the ID I received from the developer center is enabled, and that I have not exceeded the traffic usage. I am still not sure what could be wrong. If someone can give me an answer or way to fix this I'd greatly appreciate it.

code from [bingtrans example](https://github.com/bahn/bingtrans#example):

```
import bingtrans
bingtrans.set_app_id(YourAppID) # you can get your AppID at: bing.com/developers 
print bingtrans.translate('hello', 'en', 'ko')
```

Comment: Where is the code that you're using to set the app ID? Please post that.

Comment: "import bingtrans                    
bingtrans.set_app_id(YourAppID)  # you can get your AppID at: http://www.bing.com/developers/
print bingtrans.translate('hello', 'en', 'ko')"

https://github.com/bahn/bingtrans

Answer (score 2):

I'm having that problem too today, the Bing appID for Bing Translator are deprecated. It was fine until yesterday.

You can see the post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsofttranslator/thread/02054a7c-090c-46a0-a8d1-2d57e236eb4d that talk about it.

You will need to get a new Azure Marketplace token from the http://api.microsofttranslator.com website.

Comment: Thank you. As I'm understanding the link you gave to the discussion thread, any new appId that was made today and thereafter will not work. The only ones that will work are ones created yesterday and before?

Comment: It's extrange but my appId is 2 months old and i cannot make it work either. I'm also cannot able to log in into azure marketplace. I think azure is having a problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Bing AppID mechanism is deprecated and is no longer supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx

Comment: Here is an alternative to bingtrans, called py-bing: http://code.google.com/p/py-bing/

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like you need to get a correct appId. It should be 16 characters or more.

If I open this URL in the browser, it tells me that it should be that long: http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?from=en&to=ko&text=software&appId=

Comment: I do have an appId, however, I still get the error. I am running this in Ubuntu Terminal on Python if that helps at all.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. In your question, it says that your appId is 4 numbers long. It should be much bigger than that, and it should be letters and numbers.

Comment: That information posted in the quote in the original post in the information I receive back from the terminal, not anything that I input. I apologize if that wasn't clear. The part where I enter the appId, is "bingtrans.set_app_id(YourAppID)".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set your clientID and client secret, both of them are required.

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your answer? Add more code.